# sql dense_rank over partition

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to realize DENSE_RANK over id and status so that the result will look like in column 'd_rank' OR how to realize it differently
I used code below but it doesn't work as I intend

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id, status ORDER BY created) as d_rank
```

| created | id | status | d_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 55 | CREATED | 1 |
| 2023 | 55 | CREATED | 1 |
| 2024 | 55 | CLOSED | 2 |
| 2050 | 60 | REOPENED | 1 |
| 2051 | 60 | CLOSED | 2 |
| 2052 | 60 | CLOSED | 2 |

Comment: It looks like you want a ranking/sequence for each id, and status "created" should collate before "reopened" which in turn should collate before "closed".
Is that correct?

Comment: `order by case when status = 'CREATED' then 1 when status = 'REOPENED' then 2 else 3 end`

Comment: @BillJetzer No, in column STATUS can be everything. There is no logic in its statuses, just to do dense_rank over column CREATED partition by id for statuses

Comment: @EdmCoff you fiddle is correct (from the side of data and what I tried), but the result I try to have is different https://prnt.sc/RE2MjVCNcTjA

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think I had this backwards. I thought the data in your original post was what you were _getting_, but that's what you _want_. My mistake.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a better way with a single window function (as you're trying), but here are a couple of ideas. Maybe you could start with one of them: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a8ffea49cb31a6e9a7ad45ef8d980a4a